What's the translation of "aparthotel" in French?
An aparthotel is a:

a set of apartments where you can stay for a short time that offer services like a hotel, for example tea, coffee, towels and cleaning services.

What's the translation of "aparthotel" in French?
Google translate and Linguee suggest "appart'hôtel", however I never heard that term and only saw 2 webpages on Google using it.

2 pages web ? Moi j'obtiens 3 millions de résultat en français.

@XouDo hmm maybe it's because I'm in the US and Google returns results containing aparthotel  instead of appart'hôtel.

It is not "a set of apartments". It's an apartment hotel aka apart'hôtel from the French. It's been around since the 70's in France, as a term. NOT in English. That's more recent.

There are gazillions of pages about them with various spellings: appart'hôtel, appart-hôtel and appart hôtel.
Some occurrences can be found in the early seventies.
1972:

1974:

1983:

Note: The OED tells that aparthotel is a borrowing from the Spanish apartotel.


only saw 2 webpages on Google using it.

Turns out it's because I'm in the US and Google returns results containing aparthotel instead of appart'hôtel. I thought searching for "appart'hôtel" would motivate Google to return French results but in actuality Google by and large ignores the accents and apostrophe, so >99% of the returned results are in English.
To force Google to only returns French results, specify the language in Advanced Search:

or add lr=lang_fr in the URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22appart+h%C3%B4tel%22&num=100&lr=lang_fr

You get French results in the US by using: site:.fr The returns may be in English but the hotels in France. One thing is a translated site (into English) in a country domaine, another is asking for all results in French.
